# Simulación hilos java

Tags: java, hilos

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que creo una aplicación que simula una carrera.

El problema está en el bloque syncronized, aunque no entiendo por qué no funciona. A mi entender, cuando cada hilo entra en el bloque syncronized, este bloquea a otro hilo que quiera acceder al objeto; garantizando así la ejecución completa del bloque y que no genere solapamiento con otro hilo.
Lo que pretendo hacer es que el programa vaya calculando la distancia avanzada en intervalos de 1s, y éste actualice los datos (Distancia recorrida, tiempo, velocidad) en único bloque.

Entonces la salida por consola debería ser la siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero esto es en la teoría porque cuando ejecuto los distintos hilos se solapan.

Adjunto un profile para que veáis los estados de los procesos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Cuál es la manera correcta de utilizar el bloque sincronizad en este caso?

**Clase corredor**

```
 public class Corredor implements Runnable {
    private double distancia;

    public Corredor(double distancia)
    {
        this.distancia = distancia;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
       update();
    }

    public  void update()
    {
        double velocidad, aux = 0, tiempo = 0;
        try{
        while (aux < distancia)
        {
            synchronized(this){
                velocidad = velocidadPuntual(aux);
                Thread.sleep(2);
                tiempo +=2;
                aux += velocidad*2;
                System.out.println("\nCorredor: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("Distancia recorrida: "+aux);
                System.out.println("Tiempo: "+tiempo+"\n");
                if(aux > 100)
                    break;

            }
        }

        }catch(InterruptedException e){}

    }

    private double velocidadPuntual(double aux)
    {
        double velocidad;
        if(aux < 10)
                velocidad = Math.random()*5+5;
            else if(aux >= 10 && aux < 20)
                velocidad = Math.random()*5 + 7;
            else if(aux >= 20 && aux < 30)
                velocidad = Math.random()*5 + 8;
            else if(aux >= 30 && aux < 60)
                velocidad = Math.random()*5 + 10;
            else if(aux >= 60 && aux < 80)
                velocidad = Math.random()*5 + 9;
            else 
                velocidad = Math.random()*5 + 8;

        return velocidad;
    }

}
```

**Clase principal**

En la clase main creo los hilos, como podéis ver a continuación:

```
package practicasdhilos;
import carrera.Corredor;

/**
 *
 * @author ignacio
 */
public class PracticaSDHIlos {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        double prueba = 100;
        Thread Bolt = new Thread (new Corredor(prueba),"Bolt");
        Thread Aranguren = new Thread (new Corredor(prueba),"Aranguren");
        Thread Lewis = new Thread (new Corredor(prueba), "Lewis");
        Thread Powell = new Thread (new Corredor(prueba), "Powell");
        Thread Harris = new Thread (new Corredor(prueba), "Harris");
        Bolt.start();
        Aranguren.start();
        Lewis.start();
        Powell.start();
        Harris.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Muy probablemente `synchronized(this.getClass())` o simplemente  `synchronized(getClass())` puedan servir.

Comment: Funciona! ¿Podrías explicar por qué?

Comment: A que te refieres con que los hilos se solapan??

Comment: Lo que estaba buscando era que cuando un hilo ejecutase el bloque syncronized, los demás quedarán bloqueados. Al decir que se solapan era que los distintos hilos seguían ejecutando el contenido del bloque, a pesar de que éste era syncronized. No sé si me he explicado bien. Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poniendo this.getClass
Funciona porque usted al utilizar solo this hace el bloqueo solo para el objeto que esta interviniendo, el cual es redundante porque el objeto es el unico que utiliza el metodo run, pero usando el getClass lo bloqueas para todos los Objetos de ese tipo de clase, entonces ahi si entra en juego el llamado recurso compartido o zona prohibida la cual es accedida por 1 hilo simultaneamente.

Comment: ¿Y si quisiese bloquear solo un método?

Comment: Un metodo para esa clase? para todas las clases? para quienes?

Comment: Para esa clase.

Comment: Usa el metodo con la sentencia synchornized por delante de su signatura por ej:
private synchronized double velocidadPuntual(double aux)
el problema de los hilos es que lo tienes que usar con monitores, es un concepto de este tema, es algo extenso pero interesante, te recomiendo investigar.

Comment: Muy útil. Gracias.